# How to return dropdown value (using ajax) as variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi please assist me on this matter. I want dropdown selected value to reflect another text field. To do this, I set onChange function and use ajax to return the selected value. I set returned value as a php variable/session, so that I can use it through out the page. The value was successfully return but only to be displayed. I make it hidden, but have no idea how to transform it into a variable.

```
<select name="txtService" id="txtService" onchange="showService(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Select Service</option>

<?php
    $sql = "select * from tab_service where service_active = 1 Order By service_name";
    $query = $db->ExecuteSelect($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row->service_id."'>".$row->service_name."</option>";
    }
?>

</select> 
<div id="div1"></div>
```

my ajax to get and return the selected value to div1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showService(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
            return;
        }
    var xhr = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else {
        // IE5/IE6
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", "booking2.php?q="+str, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
}
```

and here in booking2.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$vals   =   @$_REQUEST['q'];
$_SESSION['SelectValue']=$vals;
?>
<input type="hidden" name="selectedServID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SelectValue'];    ?>">
```

Comment: I set the returned value $_SESSION['SelectValue'] as hidden input. but seems not working. `<?php 
 session_start();

 $vals = @$_REQUEST['q'];
 $_SESSION['SelectValue']=$vals;
?>
 <input type="hidden" name="selectedServID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SelectValue']; ?>">`

Comment: why are you making an ajax call when you can set the value to any element there itself.. and you cannot set PHP variable with javascript. javascript being a client side scripting language. http://jsfiddle.net/FwTgb/ refer this if this satisfies your requirement

Comment: @Harshada Chavan, you should make an answer with the code you made because OP is using it

Comment: thank you! i applied your suggested code but can you give me idea how to make value displayed in `<input name="selectedService" type="hidden" value="">` as a $variable? i need it to continue my if else statement

Answer (score 0):

Can you change:

```
<select name="txtService" id="txtService" onchange="showService(this.value)">
```

to this:

```
<select name="txtService" id="txtService" onchange="showService(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
```

**UPDATED:**

```
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;      // ?!?!?!? what is this doing
        return;
    }
```

Also:

```
    xhr.open("GET", "booking2.php?q="+str, true);
```

better to send as:

```
    var uri = encodeURIComponent("booking2.php?q="+str);
    xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
```

Also, can you tell me what the `str` contains in the start of the function?

Comment: thanks but can you explain a bit details cos it only returned and displayed the value. i wanna make it as a variable so that i can use it in my php codes like `if($_SESSION['SelectValue'] ==1){ something here} else { something else}` . try using hidden field but not working...

Comment: The above method is just for compatibility, some browsers might not like just the `this.value`.. Also i updated my post

Comment: i just changed my code too as what @Harshada Chavan suggested. here it is:   `onchange='javascript: showService(this);'` and my script:    `<script type="text/javascript">
 function showService(selObj){
   document.forms['f'].selectedService.value = selObj.options[selObj.options.selectedIndex].value;
 }
</script>` then the value will be displayed here    `<input name="selectedService" type="hidden" value="">` but how to set the value as $variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

$vals   =   @$_REQUEST['q'];
$_SESSION['SelectValue']=$vals;
echo $_SESSION['SelectValue'];
```

Comment: ya i did.but it will just display the result. when i used $_SESSION['SelectValue'] in codes, doesnt work. like it is empty, no value